# Should I trust X-SharePointHealthScore to predict a rate limit at Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph, resource-throttling, health

I want to execute all my requests concurrently and configure a synchronizer that will reduce the frequency of concurrent requests **before** it could exceed a rate limit at Microsoft Graph API.

The synchronizer will reduce the frequency of concurrent requests if X-SharePointHealthScore aproaches near 10 otherwise it will increase the frequency to an optimum value so that X-SharePointHealthScore is below 10.

Should I trust X-SharePointHealthScore to ensure I don't encounter a rate limit at Microsoft Graph API ?